# DB2 using pyodbc on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, db2, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a DB2 database using pyodbc on Mac OS X and I can't seem to get this going. I have had success using FreeTDS to connect to MS SQL Server under similar conditions.

First, I installed db2exc_client_952_MAC_x86_64 from IBM. After successfully installing that, I went to add the driver via ODBC Administrator.

[image: ODBC Administrator]

Then I've tried running this python:

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC Driver}; Hostname=myhost.com; Port=50300; Protocol=TCPIP; Database=DB2ET; CurrentSchema=SCHM1; UID=MYUID; PWD=MYPWD;');
```

And I receive this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[] \xf8\x92\x90\x81\x9b\xf8\x93\x90\x81\x82\xf8\x96\xb0\x81\x9d\xf8\x93\x80\x81\x83\xf8\x88\x80\x81\x89\xf8\x9c\xa0\x81\x84\xf8\x9d\xa0\x81\xa9\xf8\x9c\xa0\x81\xa5\xf8\x88\x80\x81\x9d\xf8\x94\x90\x81\x93\xf8\x8c\x90\x81\x8c\xf8\x8c\xa0\x80\xb0\xf8\x93\xa0\x80\xb4\xf8\x88\x80\x80\xa0\xf8\x88\x80\x81\x81\xf8\x98\x90\x81\xa4\xf8\x98\x90\x81\xb4\xf8\x98\x90\x81\xa2\xf8\x99\x90\x81\xb3\xf8\x98\xb0\x80\xa0\xf8\x9b\xa0\x81\xaf\xf8\x99\x90\x81\xae\xf8\x9d\x80\x81\xa3\xf8\x9b\xb0\x81\xa9\xf8\x88\x80\x81\xae\xf8\x9b\xb0\x81\xa4\xf8\x9c\xb0\x81\xa5\xf8\x9b\xa0\x80\xa0\xf8\x9d\x80\x81\xaf\xf8\x99\x90\x80\xa0\xf8\x9a\x90\x81\xb8\xf8\x9d\x80\x81\xb3\xf8\x88\x80\x80\xae\xf8\x94\xb0\x80\xa0\xf8\x93\x80\x81\x91\xf8\x95\x80\x81\x93\xf8\x95\x80\x81\x81\xf8\x8f\x90\x81\x85\xf8\x8e\x80\x80\xb0\xf8\x8c\x80\x80\xb0\xf2\xa0\x80\xb3\xfc\xa0\x9c\xb0\x80\x80\xfd\xa1\x99\x82\x81\xa1\xfd\xa1\x98\xa6\x85\xb4\xfd\xa9\x88\x86\x95\xb3\xfd\x82\x91\x82\x81\xae\xfd\xaf\x99\xa2\x80\xb2\xfd\x96\x93\x92\x81\xb2\xfd\x93\x82\xa2\xb9\x93\xff\x7f (-1024) (SQLDriverConnect)')

I gathered from searching that HY000 may be a connectionString problem, but I'm not sure how to decipher the rest of the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figure this one out? Im having trouble setting up ODBC drivers in ODBC Adminstrator.

Comment: @cabe56 no I didn't figure this out unfortunately. My next thought was to use something like http://py4j.sourceforge.net/index.html because I can access DB2 fine using DbVisualizer on my Mac (which I believe uses JAVA under the hood)

Answer (score 1):

It appears connection strings vary by database and the connection string you are using is not compatible with DB2.

Here's some DB2 example connection strings:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/ibm-db2

Here's the best reference I could find as to what is valid in a DB2 connection string:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2FDB2ConnectionClass.html

Based on that, I'd convert your connection string from:

```
Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC Driver}; Hostname=myhost.com; Port=50300; Protocol=TCPIP; Database=DB2ET; CurrentSchema=SCHM1; UID=MYUID; PWD=MYPWD;
```

To:

```
Driver={IBM DB2 ODBC Driver}; Server=myhost.com:50300; Database=DB2ET; CurrentSchema=SCHM1; UID=MYUID; PWD=MYPWD;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm still seeing the same garbled error after changing to that connection string. I've tried more than 10 varieties of connection strings and none have worked so far. The one in my original post is actually one that works on Windows.

Comment: Hhmmm. This link http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000584.html indicates that HY000 means that it wanted to prompt for a dialog because info in the connection string isn't sufficient. Is there some kind of policy set on the database server that won't allow you to inline UID and PWD in the connection string? Have you tried a connection string without UID and PWD just to see what happens? And for that matter, without Database and CurrentSchema?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what my connection string looks like in PHP (I know you're using Python but I think they're very similar):

```
$this->db_connection = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=10.xxx.xxx.xxx;PROTOCOL=TCPIP", $temp_username, $temp_password);
```

Notice that I say "SYSTEM=..." and you say "Hostname=..." - I think that could be important.

Is your DSN set up completely? On my Linux machines I have two files that contain all of our configuration information for DSN's.

odbc.ini

```
[primary]
Description             = primary
Driver                  = iSeries Access ODBC Driver
System                  = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
UserID                  = xxxxxxxxxx
Password                = xxxxxxxxxx
Naming                  = 0
DefaultLibraries        = QGPL
Database                = xxxxxxxxxx
ConnectionType          = 0
CommitMode              = 2
ExtendedDynamic         = 0
DefaultPkgLibrary       = QGPL
DefaultPackage          = A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
AllowDataCompression    = 1
LibraryView             = 0
AllowUnsupportedChar    = 0
ForceTranslation        = 0
Trace                   = 0
```

and odbcinst.ini

```
[iSeries Access ODBC Driver]
Description     = iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver          = /usr/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
NOTE1           = If using unixODBC 2.2.11 or later and you want the 32 and 64-bit ODBC drivers to share DSN's,
NOTE2           = the following Driver64/Setup64 keywords will provide that support.
Driver64        = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading       = 2
DontDLClose     = 1
UsageCount      = 1
```

I believe you enter similar information in the dialog you show, probably under the DSN tab.

Have you enabled ODBC tracing?  To do this in Linux I have to add this to the odbcinst.ini file:

```
[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/odbc.log
```

This dumped a LOT of information for me and helped to diagnose some problems I've had in the past.

According to this page (http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ConnectionStrings), "The most important thing to know is that pyodbc does not even look at the connection string -- it is passed directly to SQLDriverConnect unmodified." If that's true then changing your "Hostname" to "SYSTEM" should do the trick.

EDIT

Any chance this could be a problem with encoding? Unicode trying to talk to a UTF-8 server (or something similar)?  Have you tried setting the CCSID? When you configure the driver do you have options such as "BinAsChar", "CCSID" or "Host CCSID"?

By default I believe the CCSID is 37 (US/Canada) and I think Unicode is 1208.

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a User DSN using a driver and then use the DSN in the connect() method?

```
pyodbc.connect( 'DSN=MYDSN;UID=MYUSER;PWD=MYPASS' )
```

And by the way using any driver other than the "iSeries Access ODBC Driver" might raise those DB2 licensing errors. Maybe this is what the message is saying.

The driver is installed when you install "IBM i Access for Windows 7.1"